# Site edit issue for a component presentation

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

I have a DD4T website in Tridion 2013 where Site edit is also functional.

I am facing issue with getting the lock symbol for a component presentation added in couple of pages hence not able to edit it via XPM. The same presentation if added in any other page is working and having the lock symbol.

Not sure what is wrong with those two pages as the border is properly formed but no lock symbol is there. Any input for this please.

Comment: What color is the border? Are the other pages within the same session (same or different browser and/or user)? And are all pages published or at least have an updated session preview?

Comment: Grey color. Even other components in those two pages has Update Preview and shows the lock but the lock is not there for that particular comp. Yes, other pages in same session and all browsers show the lock except these two. All pages are published.

Comment: Ok, grey means not-editable at this time for the current user. Functionally the other reasons could be it is the same Component in different Publications (where it's localized and locked in one Publication) or it's not really the _same_ Component. For example, if using Page Types, it's easy to create Component Presentations that look exactly the same. Check the tcm URLs and version history, looking specifically for minor versions suggesting the item really is locked (and by whom).

Comment: I don't see the minor version in history(all are in xx.0) and also no lock is there for the comp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get component lock icon with border, the component with experience manager tag should be embedded in any html tag (for e.g. div).

In your case, check the pages where you are getting the lock icon, your component rendering would have been inside some html tag.

Also, verify properties to enable experience manger at page and page template level, verify that.

Comment: Yes, inside a div. The comp renders with same CT in all the pages - but in two of the pages lock is not there and other pages have the lock for the same comp presentation.

Comment: Updated answer to include more details

Comment: Is the problem that you can edit the component in XPM (and that should not be possible) or is the problem that it just doesn't show the lock symbol (as a styling issue)?

Comment: The same component shows lock in all other pages except two. I can edit them using Open in Form view option but no lock to edit via on browser.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so the problem were couple of other comps in the page whose view was not correct w.r.t XPM as @Html.SiteEditComponentPresentation(Model) was not inside any div and this was causing the comps with correct views to loose their HTML.

Comment: What extra information that you have shared? This was already given in the answer that I had provided. So I don't see any point of creating new answer.